# Why does adding data lead to smaller size of HDF file created by Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I was consolidating bike rental data into a DataFrame stored in a HDF file and wanted to see how much adding dates would increase the file size. To my surprise, it didn't, rather the resulting file would be smaller when I added a column for dates.

Below is my code and some experimentation results. To me, the last two file sizes seem logical, but the first one is surprising. What causes the file size to shrink even when new data is added?

```
In [1]:

import pandas as pd
import re
import os
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

def get_data_links():
    '''
    Returns list of filenames parsed from http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/.
    Only names of form "stations_yyyymmddThhmmssZ" are returned.
    '''

    res = get('http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

    return [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a') if re.match('stations_\d{8}T\d{6}Z', link['href'])]

def save_new_data(new_data, filename):
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename)

    if not '/data' in store.keys():
        store['data'] = pd.DataFrame()

    store['data'] = store['data'].append(new_data)
    store.close()

def get_data(link_list, with_date):
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    bad_data = 0

    for link in link_list:
        filename = 'http://dev.hsl.fi/tmp/citybikes/' + link

        try:
            new_data = pd.read_json(filename)
            new_data = new_data.result.apply(pd.Series)
            if with_date:
                new_data['date'] = pd.Timestamp(link.split("_")[1])
            data = data.append(new_data)
        except:
            bad_data += 1
            continue

    print("Result shape: " + str(data.shape))
    print("Number of good files: " + str(len(link_list) - bad_data))
    print("Number of bad files: " + str(bad_data))
    return data

def print_shape_size(filename):
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
    print(filename + " data shape: " + str(store['data'].shape) + ", size: " + str(os.path.getsize(filename)))
    store.close()

links = get_data_links()
​
data_without_dates = get_data(links[0:1000], False)
data_with_dates = get_data(links[0:1000], True)
​
save_new_data(data_without_dates, 'data_without_dates.h5')
save_new_data(data_with_dates, 'data_with_dates.h5')
save_new_data(data_with_dates.drop('date', axis=1), 'data_with_dates_dropped.h5')

print_shape_size('data_without_dates.h5')
print_shape_size('data_with_dates.h5')
print_shape_size('data_with_dates_dropped.h5')
```

Results in:

```
Out[1]:

Result shape: (136177, 7)
Number of good files: 958
Number of bad files: 42

Result shape: (136177, 8)
Number of good files: 958
Number of bad files: 42

data_without_dates.h5 data shape: (136177, 7), size: 12964632
data_with_dates.h5 data shape: (136177, 8), size: 10253592
data_with_dates_dropped.h5 data shape: (136177, 7), size: 9559352
```

*(Python 3.6.1, Pandas 0.20.1)*

Comment: How many times did you run this? Does the size stay consistent every time you run it?

Comment: @flyingmeatball, yes the sizes stay exactly the same every time I run it.